# What do I do if I want to make an if statement that is dependent on an output? (Im running python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm making a tip calculator and I want to make it so that if it prints a message because the input was not a float, then it reads the fact that it prints that message and goes back to the original input and makes you try again so can i do something like:

```
if print("No stupid use a number."):
      return input("Bill before tax.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work.

```
def calc_tip(total):
    total = float(total)
    return total * 0.1, total * 0.15, total * 0.2


while True:
    try:
        tip10, tip15, tip20 = calc_tip(input("Enter total before tax: "))
    except ValueError as e:
        print("input a number")
    else:
        break

print('Tip amount: 10%% = $%0.2f, 15%% = $%0.2f, 20%% = $%0.2f' %
      (tip10, tip15, tip20))
```